# SIFT implementation of OCR in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ocr, sift

So for our Final Year Project we are making a nifty lil app that lets a user take pictures  of visiting cards from their cell phone, apply OCR on it and get all the required info in printable form... My problem is that SIFT is rotation invariant i.e it can not differentiate between a "u" and an "n" and other such words and numbers. I would really appreciate if you share any ideas that you folks mite have or come up with for overcoming this problem. :)
Thank you.

Comment: The feature that leads SIFT to be unable to differentiate between a "u" and an "n" is rotation invariance, not scale invariance. Scale invariance means that it doesn't distinguish between different sizes of things. You can usually turn off rotation invariance in whatever SIFT implementation you end up using.

Comment: What SIFT implementation are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your input, and Yes I know the difference between scale and rotation invariance... I must have gotten confused while writing my question. The implementation of SIFT we are using was originally designed and written for pushto cursive script... We have modified it to suit our specific problem. You can read about it here.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5638470

Comment: Could you be more specific about how I can turn off the rotation invariance feature? Should I paste the code here?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the implementation that you're using. There should be a section in the code that determines dominant orientation of a SIFT patch and then adjusts all of the orientations to be relative to that dominant orientation. If there isn't a boolean flag to change this behaviour, you could just hard-code the dominant orientation to equal 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to strip that image
then use dilute, if that does not work use neural network

Comment: Thank you sir, could you further elaborate your answer? I'm afraid I'm a novice and would welcome any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the following paper? :-)
[Scale and rotation invariant recognition of cursive Pashto script using SIFT features](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5638470)

Comment: Yes Sir, we have in detail. Dr Hassan Amin was our supervisor before he relocated to Lahore. We even have the source code for the pashto cursive script version, but the nature of our problem is a bit different. So we have come up with an approach that is unique. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that SIFT will have difficulties working out 'u' and 'n' similar characters but if you really want to stick with SIFT (your final project is probably finished now...) you could always apply some pre-processing on images like 'u' and 'n' by putting underlines under them in right orientation and let SIFT know that 'u' with underline is 'u' etc.